# How to handle files that opened a program

Tags: java, file

When my Java file-processing program is opened by an *Open With...* command, or is set as a file's default program, how do I handle the file that opened it.

Is it passed as a command line argument?
In what format?

And how about programs, wrapped in an .exe wrapper, or compiled with an AOT compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should receive the file's path as an argument in main().

See [Using command-line argument for passing files to a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055318/using-command-line-argument-for-passing-files-to-a-program) (maybe duplicated?)

Comment: Well,when i tried it on a text file, it worked, but not on images, why?

Answer (score 1):

Create an executable of your Java File processing program. Please read this-[**creating executable file**](http://dasha.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) if you want to know, how to create executable?

In command line, you may say: `executable FileName.ext`

`FileName.ext` will be available in your `main` program's `args[0]` attribute.
 i.e.

```
       public static void main(String[] args){
           String fileName = args[0];
        }
```

Comment: I get `'executable' is not recognized as an internal or external command` etc., .

Comment: @M.M.: How did you create the executable file? By executable, I meant the executable fine name. Please read this-[**creating executable file**](http://dasha.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) if you want to know, how to create executable? By the way, I see you have already accepted one answer. Are you still looking for some solution?

Answer (score 1):

Launch the app. with [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and declare an interest in the file-type within the launch file (JNLP).

The path to the `File` will be passed as a `String` as the 2nd argument to the `main`.  The 1st argument will be either `-edit/open` (I forget) or `-print`.

> And how about programs, wrapped in an .exe wrapper, or compiled with an AOT compiler?

How about asking that on a separate question?  If deploying with JWS, we would use Jar(s).