# how to pass inputs to java using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to get the user input using the following code but on running it gives the error that Arrayindexoutofbounds.
Don't know what is the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int T = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    PercolationStats stats = new PercolationStats(
            Integer.parseInt(args[0]), T);
    double mean = stats.mean();
    StdOut.println("mean = " + mean);
    double stddev = stats.stddev();
    StdOut.println("stddev = " + stddev);
    double d = (1.96 * stddev) / Math.sqrt(T);
    StdOut.println("95% confidence interval = " + (mean - d) + ", "
            + (mean + d));
}
```

Comment: What line is throwing the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds complaints? What's does the Eclipse debugger tell you is in args? (I'm betting that you failed to set up your launch configuration to pass and/or prompt for command-line arguments, and args is empty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arguments to a Java program via Eclipse, you should use the **Arguments** tab in Run > Run Configurations. Example:

**Arguments**

[image]

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    System.out.println(args[2]);
}
```

**Result**

```
33
twitter
400.23
```

Comment: Then if i want have a continous input like while(args[0]!=EOF){ add to array } How can we implement this.

Comment: If that's the case, you're better off passing a filename into the first argument. You can then parse that file during processing. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055318/using-command-line-argument-for-passing-files-to-a-program

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your input parameters in following way in Eclipse:
click menu Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments
in Program arguments put your arguments, which will be loaded to "String [] args"
you could just separate your arguments by space:

e.g.

1 2 3

and your args = {1,2,3}

Comment: Then if i want have a continous input like while(args[0]!=EOF){ add to array } How can we implement this.

Comment: you can use java bufferedreader to read your input from a file. You can refer the example in this link: [How to read file in Java – BufferedReader](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)