# Resolving a bufferReader error

Tags: java

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error.

Here is a small snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
    Fileread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Error reading in file");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I'm reading in a text file that is 50+ lines. I am somewhat new to just using `args[]` array to read in initial input. So forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055318/using-command-line-argument-for-passing-files-to-a-program

Comment: do you pass your path to your file as the first program argument?

Comment: I am doing file.txt || java Memory: I am assuming that is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not get a FileNotFoundException, it is safe to say that your exception is related to your arguments i.e. arg[0]...

How are you running your java class? to be able to run it properly you need to run it like this. .
i.e. if class name is Memory and filename is Memory.java then you compile it using javac Memory.java and you run it like this..

```
java Memory C:\abc.txt
```